# Adding leading zeros for only numeric character id

Tags: python, pandas, leading-zero

I know how to add leading zeros for all values in pandas column. But my pandas column 'id' involves both numeric character like '83948', '848439' and Alphanumeric character like 'dy348dn', '494rd7f'. What I want is only add zeros for the numeric character until it reaches to 10, how can we do that?

Comment: Can you provide a short reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to apply padding only on ids that are completely numeric. In this case, you can use `isnumeric()` on a string (for example, `mystring.isnumeric()`) in order to check if the string **contains only numbers**. If the condition is satisfied, you can apply your padding rule.

Comment: Thanks, so like a ifelse condition?

Comment: Exactly. You can do `if id.isnumeric(): id = apply_padding(id)` or something like that according to how your code is structured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask with `str.isdigit` and boolean indexing with `str.zfill`:

```
mask = df['col'].str.isdigit()
df.loc[mask, 'col'] = df.loc[mask, 'col'].str.zfill(10)
```

Output:

```
          col
0  0000083948
1  0000848439
2     dy348dn
3     494rd7f
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['83948', '848439', 'dy348dn', '494rd7f']})
```